# Views not appearing on iPhone as they do in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, size, uistoryboard

In the storyboard I have the views set up like this:

[image]

Now I have some code which changes the text and image background color etc. but no size changes are in the code.

This is how it turns out on the iPhone:

[image]

You see the 'published by' just decides to resize its width for no reason.

I have tried adding all missing constraints,

I have tried adding a constraint for 'same width' for the body view and the 'published by' view.

Nothing.

Can anyone give me an explanation why something like this might happen?

Comment: I don't know but setting a `leading` and `trailing` constraint for the _"Publish"_ `UILabel` should be enough

Comment: You can even try just having a leading, top & bottom on publish but don't set a width on the label either.

Comment: Do I set the leading and trailing go the 'published by' view equal to that of the body, by selecting the 2?

Comment: Gregory I have post my answer with screen shot which constraint will set for that button, please have a look on it. It will solve your problem more clearly and easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

set publication button constraint as per screenshot.
I hope it will help you and will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just using a bottom & leading worked for me as shown.

[image]